# Reflection, contravariance and polymorphism

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have a base class (abstract) with multiple implementations, and some of them contain collection properties of other implementations - like so:

```
class BigThing : BaseThing
{
    /* other properties omitted for brevity */
    List<SquareThing> Squares { get; set; }
    List<LittleThing> SmallThings { get; set;}
    /* etc. */
}
```

Now sometimes I get a BigThing and I need to map it to another BigThing, along with all of its collections of BaseThings. However, when this happens, I need to be able to tell if a BaseThing in a collection from the source BigThing is a *new* BaseThing, and thus should be Add()-ed to the destination BigThing's collection, or if it's an *existing* BaseThing that should be mapped to one of the BaseThings that already exist in the destination collection. Each implementation of BaseThing has a different set of matching criteria on which it should be evaluated for new-ness. I have the following generic extension method to evaluate this:

```
static void UpdateOrCreateThing<T>(this T candidate, ICollection<T> destinationEntities) where T : BaseThing
{
    var thingToUpdate = destinationEntites.FirstOrDefault(candidate.ThingMatchingCriteria);
    if (thingToUpdate == null) /* Create new thing and add to destinationEntities */
    else /* Map thing */
}
```

Which works fine. However I think I am getting lost with the method that deals in BigThings. I want to make this method generic because there are a few different kinds of BigThings, and I don't want to have to write methods for each, and if I add collection properties I don't want to have to change my methods. I have written the following generic method that makes use of reflection, but it is not

```
void MapThing(T sourceThing, T destinationThing) where T : BaseThing
{
    //Take care of first-level properties
    Mapper.Map(sourceThing, destinationThing);

    //Now find all properties which are collections
    var collectionPropertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => typeof(ICollection).IsAssignableFrom(p.PropertyType));

    //Get property values for source and destination
    var sourceProperties = collectionPropertyInfo.Select(p => p.GetValue(sourceThing));
    var destinationProperties = collectionPropertyInfo.Select(p => p.GetValue(destinationThing));

    //Now loop through collection properties and call extension method on each item
    for (int i = 0; i < collectionPropertyInfo.Count; i++)
    {
        //These casts make me suspicious, although they do work and the values are retained
        var thisSourcePropertyCollection = sourceProperties[i] as ICollection;
        var sourcePropertyCollectionAsThings = thisSourcePropertyCollection.Cast<BaseThing>();
        //Repeat for destination properties

        var thisDestinationPropertyCollection = destinationProperties[i] as ICollection;
        var destinationPropertyCollectionAsThings = thisDestinationPropertyCollection.Cast<BaseThing>();

        foreach (BaseThing thing in sourcePropertyCollectionAsThings)
        {
            thing.UpdateOrCreateThing(destinationPropertyCollectionAsThings);
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs, and the extension method runs successfully (matching and mapping as expected), but the collection property values in `destinationThing` remain unchanged. I suspect I have lost the reference to the original `destinationThing` properties with all the casting and assigning to other variables and so on. Is my approach here fundamentally flawed? Am I missing a more obvious solution? Or is there some simple bug in my code that's leading to the incorrect behavior?

Comment: your title needs an "...Oh My!" at the end  ;)

Comment: I considered it :) but I fear the Wizards of Oz / SE mods ;)

Comment: Unfortunately, you don't show all of the code. So no one can see how you're initializing the "destinationPropertyCollectionAsThings" object. And naturally, it's that collection that seems at the core of the issue. You really should post a concise-but-complete code example that reliably demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I left those lines out as they were identical to the ones for the source, but I have now edited them in. If it is still unclear I will create a small console app tonight which recreates the issue and post that tonight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without thinking too much, I'd say you have fallen to a inheritance abuse trap, and now trying to save yourself, you might want to consider **how can you solve your problem** while ditching the existing design which leads you to do such things at the first place. I know, this is painful, but it's an investment in future :-)

That said,

```
   var destinationPropertyCollectionAsThings = 
       thisDestinationPropertyCollection.Cast<BaseThing>();

    foreach (BaseThing thing in sourcePropertyCollectionAsThings)
    {
        thing.UpdateOrCreateThing(destinationPropertyCollectionAsThings);
    }
```

You are losing your `ICollection` when you use Linq `Cast` operator that creates the new `IEnumerable<BaseThing>`. You can't use contravariance either, because `ICollection`does not support it. If it would, you'd get away with `as ICollection<BaseThing>` which would be nice.

Instead, you have to build the generic method call dynamically, and invoke it. The simplest way is probably using `dynamic` keyword, and let the runtime figure out, as such:

```
thing.UpdateOrCreateThing((dynamic)thisDestinationPropertyCollection);
```

Comment: Thank you Chris. I ended up adding my mapping method as an abstract instance method on BaseThing - not as nice as the reflection version, but a bit more obvious and hopefully maintainers will not forget to update the Map method since its in the same class :) Your answer did help me understand why my code was not working. Thanks again!